# is it possible retrieve 2 values from this code?

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row, corresponding-records

```
<a href="deleteresnext.php?rid=< ?php echo $row->rid ?>" 
   onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel reservation?');" >
     Delete
</a>
```

Can I retrieve 2 values using this code ? Because I need it to another php file, I would like to retrieve rid and roomid by the code above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can add another parameter to that URL:

```
<a href="deleteresnext.php?rid=<?php echo $row->rid; ?>&roomid=<?php echo $row->roomid; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel reservation?');" >Delete</a>
```

Comment: where would i put that code ?

Comment: @renz, You can upvote and/or accept this answer by clicking on the up arrow and the hollow checkmark. Thanks!

Comment: oh sure i forgot. thanks to you again man.